# получить массив POST с другого сайта в wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть 2 сайта из первого надо отправить массив POST, а на втором принять и обработать, делаю таким образом: 
На сайте "http://test1.com" отправляю таким методом данные POST на "http://test2.com"

```
$url = 'http://test2.com';
$params = array(
    'data_send' => $data_send, //$_POST['data_send']
);
 file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => http_build_query($params)
    )
)));
```

На "http://test2.com" в теме function.php принимаю:

```
    if(isset($_POST['data_send'])){
var_dump($_POST['data_send']);}
```

Но ничего нет, на чистом PHP такой пример у меня работал, может кто подскажет как на wordpress такое правильно реализовать

Comment: а с чего взяли что function.php должен принимать ваш запрос ?  если хотите таким методом извращатся ( :) )  и получать данные, укажите полный путь к файлу  $url = 'http://test2.com/wp-content\themes\your_theme\function.php'; - но то что вы хотите сделать это ужас

Comment: @Arsen скажите как не по ужасному сделать, наставьте на правильный путь?

Comment: Если скажете что за данные хотите получить на втором сайте и где хотите использовать - помогу ))

Comment: @Arsen тот метод не работает приводит к ошибке  'Call to undefined function get_template_directory()' :( Вообщем ситуация такая я получаю массив данных из БД и нужно передать эти данные на второй сайт, на втором сайте главное каким то образом выловить этот post а там уже разберусь)

Comment: Изучай https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_APIs в частности https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отправка запроса на сайт test2.com:

```
$body   = array(
    'data_send' => $data_send,
);
$result = wp_remote_post( 'http://test2.com', array(
    'method'      => 'POST',
    'redirection' => 1,
    'httpversion' => '1.0',
    'blocking'    => true,
    'headers'     => array(),
    'body'        => $body,
    'cookies'     => array(),
) );
if ( is_wp_error( $result ) ) {
    // вернуть ошибку
}

$body     = $result['body'];
$body_array     = json_decode( $body );
$success = $body_array->success;
if ( ! $success ) {
    // вернуть ошибку
}
$data = $body_array->data; // Это ответ от test2.com
```

Приём, обработка запроса и отправка ответа на сайте test2.com:

```
add_action( 'init', 'get_request' );
function get_request() {
    if ( isset( $_POST[ 'data_send' ] ) ) {
        $data = $_POST[ 'data_send' ];
        // Обработка данных,
        // установка флага $result
        // создание (если нужно) массива возвращаемых данных $data
        if ( $result ) {
            wp_send_json_success( $data );
        } else {
            wp_send_json_error();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: $_POST[ 'data_send' ]  не приходит в functions.php, $body_array почему-то пуст, а в if ( ! $success ) ошибка

Comment: ну а так вроде все работает, спасибо